# Is there a Windows 10 version of the Windows 7 explorer "Favorites"?

Tags: windows-10

Does anyone know if there is a 3rd party app or something that will add the Favorites feature that was available in Explorer on Windows 7, to Windows 10?

NOTE: Quick Access is not a valid replacement for Favorites as it doesn't allow shortcuts (as a result you can't rename items).

Comment: May I know if your question is how to move Internet Explorer favorites to a new PC (from Windows 7 to Windows 10)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IE. It is the Favorites list of shortcuts that shows on the left pane of a file Explorer window. There is something similar in Win10 called Quick Access; but much less useful.